# Pandas plot area change axis values

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `dataframe.plot.are` functionality. I have data like this (`DF1`):

```
   --myDF1Column1, myDF1Column2, myDF1Column3, myDF1Column4
0.10266666667,0,0.08,0.13
0.17,0,0.08,0.117
0.081333333333,0,0.108,0.1
```

and in another `dataframe`, I have values, say (`DF2`):
   --myDF2Column
    111,
    222,
    223

So, when I do `DF1.plot.area`, it gives me figure like this:
[image]

But actually, I want the `X` values of this figure to be `DF2.myDF2Column`. For example,instead of `0` it should be `111` and instead of `25` it would be `223`. Any ideas?

Comment: could try `DF1.index = DF2.myDF2Column` before plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, as your plot doesn't seem to be produced by your example, but here's what I think you want to do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[0.10266666667,0,0.08,0.13], "col2":  [0.17,0,0.08,0.117], "col3": [0.081333333333,0,0.108,0.1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[111,222,333,444]})

df1.plot.area()

df1.index = df2.col1

df1.plot.area()
```

Output:
[image]

`df.plot.area` will put the index of the dataframe on the x-axis, so if you want whatever is in `df2` to appear on your x-axis, you can simply assign it as the index. Note that this wouldn't work in your example as you'd need `len(df1)==len(df2)`, which is why I'm not sure I understood entirely what you're trying to do!

Comment: Nice, I think you need add notice indexes values has to be same in both Dataframes.

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand the comment - why would the values of the index need to be the same? Wouldn't this work just as well with `df2 = pd.DataFrame({"myDF2col1":[111,222,333,444]}, index=[5,6,7,8])`?

Comment: Ok, then it is ok, I think something more complicated.